# how to pass ip address and portnumber as url

Tags: http, https

To pass url i have ip address and port number , how can that be send as http url

```
ex: ip address 10.5.90.948
port number as 71
http://10.5.90.948/71
```

does that takes to the url? if not how it can be passes as http address.

thanks,

michaeld

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
http://10.5.90.948:71

scheme://host:port
```

Answer (score 5):

`http://ip:port/` - e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`

(Also, I expect it's just a made up example, but the IP address you quoted is of course not valid)