# How can I make a request to an api that is on a different port than the usual one

Tags: laravel, api, server, request, client-server

this is my code but I can only define the url where it is located but not the port where it is located

```
public function index (Request $request)
{
    $client = new Client([
        //url de base con la que se hace la peticion
        'base_uri' => 'https://xx.x.xx.xxx/api/',
        //tiempo de espera para conectar a la api
        'timeout'  => 5.0,
    ]);
    $national_id=$request->national_id;    
    $response = $client->request('GET', "clientes/?national_id=$national_id");

    $user= ($response->getBody()->getContents());
    if(!empty($user) ||$user=="[]" || $user=="{}" || $user="[{}]"){
        return view('cliente.nuevo');
    }else{    
    return view('cliente.mostrar',compact('user'));
    } 
        
}
```

Comment: `https://xx.x.xx.xxx:{PORT}/api/`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to pass ip address and portnumber as url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940120/how-to-pass-ip-address-and-portnumber-as-url)